# Using two dataframes and their columns in mutate or other dplyr functions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to determine the difference between two dates, but from separate dataframes in R. This is one dataframe lets say `d1`

```
id      date        value        
2222    11/1/12     22.65     
2222    11/2/12     23.11     
20100   10/30/12    35.21       
20100   11/2/12     38.97     
20103   10/30/12    57.98     
20103   10/31/12    60.83
```

This is another lets say `d2`

```
id      date        value
2222    10/30/12    21.01      
2222    10/31/12    22.04                 
20100   10/31/12    37.07      
20100   11/1/12     38.17           
20103   10/29/12    57.98      
20103   10/16/12    60.83
```

My expected output would be

```
   Datediff
    2 day
    2 day          
    -1 day
    1 day     
    1 day
    15 day
```

I tried using on `d1` in the mutate argument and then directly call the column for `date` from `d2`

```r
data_RN<-d1 %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(datediff= d1$date-d2$date)
```

I am also getting the error:

> Error: Column `datediff` must be length 201 (the group size) or one, not 1000
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In Ops.factor(Call_date, df2$date) :
>     ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

## Edit:

I would also like to know how I would find the difference in datetime in minutes

Comment: I think you're better off doing a `merge` first by ID perhaps?

Comment: Are your data frames the same size (Error)? Also you need to convert your `date` to proper date format (warning) prior to subtracting. I think you should be better off merging the two data frames and then subtracting

Comment: Yes I shall try the conversion of date format

Comment: The question is updated

Comment: Sorry, I had used the wrong time diff values, I have updated it. Also im saying if I had a case where I had datetime, how would I go about that

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem lies in `group_by(id)`. Delete this element and so you get what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1<-tribble(~id     ,~ date   ,~     value ,       
         2222  ,  "11/1/12"   ,  22.65  ,   
         2222   , "11/2/12"  ,   23.11  ,   
         20100  , "10/30/12" ,   35.21    ,   
         20100 ,  "11/2/12"   ,  38.97  ,   
         20103 ,  "10/30/12"  ,  57.98  ,   
         20103 ,  "10/31/12" ,   60.83    )

df2<-tribble(~id   ,~   date     ,~   value,
         2222 ,   "10/30/12"  ,  21.01  ,    
         2222 ,   "10/31/12" ,   22.04 ,                
         20100  , "10/31/12"  ,  37.07  ,    
         20100,   "11/1/12"  ,   38.17 ,          
         20103 ,  "10/29/12"   , 57.98 ,     
         20103 ,  "10/16/12" ,   60.83    )

df1<-df1%>%mutate(date= as.Date(df1$date,format= "%m/%d/%y"))
df2<-df2%>%mutate(date= as.Date(df2$date,format= "%m/%d/%y"))

data_RN<-df1 %>%mutate(datediff= df1$date-df2$date)

Output:

# A tibble: 6 x 4
     id date       value      datediff
   <dbl> <date>     <date>     <drtn>  
1  2222 2012-11-01 2012-11-01  2 days 
2  2222 2012-11-02 2012-11-02  2 days 
3 20100 2012-10-30 2012-10-30 -1 days 
4 20100 2012-11-02 2012-11-02  1 days 
5 20103 2012-10-30 2012-10-30  1 days 
6 20103 2012-10-31 2012-10-31 15 days
```

Comment: What if I had a datetime field, then how would I show that? like I wanted to find the difference in terms of minutes?

Comment: Also your code is giving the same error I showed before

Answer (score 0):

If you have date-time values you might need to change the `date` to `POSIXct` class based on the `format` you have (read `?strptime`), also `order` by `id` so that we have all the data arranged properly and then use `difftime` with `units` specified as `"mins"` for minutes.

```
d1 <- transform(d1, date = as.POSIXct(date, format = "%m/%d/%y"))
d11 <- d1[order(d1$id), ]

d2 <- transform(d2, date = as.POSIXct(date, format = "%m/%d/%y"))
d22 <- d2[order(d2$id), ]

difftime(d11$date, d22$date, units = "mins")
#Time differences in mins
#[1]  2880  2880 -1440  1440  1440 21600
```